# Linq Distinct in one line

Tags: vb.net, linq, distinct

Im trying to make the following snippet into one line. Im struggling with it but
I always get compiler warning.

```
Dim puertas As VehiculoType() = From item In ListaVehiculos _
              Select New VehiculoType() With _
              {.Puertas = item.Puertas}


Dim sel As VehiculoType() = (From item In puertas Select item).Distinct
```

How can I make the linq selection including the distinct in one statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `Distinct` call to the first line:

```
Dim puertas As VehiculoType() = (From item In ListaVehiculos _
              Select New VehiculoType() With _
              {.Puertas = item.Puertas}).Distinct
```

Comment: I was writing (Select New VehiculoType() With _
              {.Puertas = item.Puertas}).Distinct intead of opening in From. thanks!

Comment: ONe little question How can I cast the result to class? It is giving me dictint iterator exception